# Drupal Views display newest content per taxonomy limit to one node

Tags: drupal-6, view, drupal-views

I want to create a view where all 5 of my taxonomy terms are displayed and it then displays the latest node published but this is limited by 1. For Example:

> Tax Term 1
>   Latest node published
>
> Tax Term 2
>   Latest node published
>
> etc etc

Currently I'm grouping by taxonomy term so it's displaying all nodes published then sorted by published date desc. I can't quite figure out how to limit the nodes to only show one item per taxonomy term.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

This is possible with Views 3. I've tested this on D7, but should work on D6 also.

1. Add a new view of type - Taxonomy terms
2. Add relationship - Taxonomy term: Representative node
3. Other - Use aggregation: Yes
4. Add field - Content: Title. Change Aggregation settings to Group results together

Comment: Is there any way if I want to limit the display for more than one nodes per taxonomy?

Comment: I haven't used views in a while, but I don't believe there is a way.

Comment: On performing the above four steps, I get this error: `Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 2 column(s)`

Answer (score 1):

It's not great if you have a lot of nodes, but I've done this in other cases by using a filter for "Promoted to front page" - then you simple make sure you only promote one node at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a combination of panels ans views.
First, create a (or use the default) view for nodes which takes a taxonomy term as argument. Second, create a panels page containing five regions. Each region is to be filled with a view (in fact it's going to be the same view from step one, but with different arguments). Within panels ui you can restrict the number of shown entries of each view, set this value to one to have only one article be shown per term.

Panels: http://drupal.org/project/panels

Views: http://drupal.org/project/views

Comment: Hi, I'm already using panels on the page I want the block on, ideally I don't want to use mini panels either. I'll keep searching.

Comment: Oh, you want to have block. Didn't find that info in the question. Then Panels won't be a solution, of course.
But in that case, you can just create five displays of type block in the appropiate view and limit each display to show only the last entry. That way you'll get five blocks (each showing the last node of one of the five terms) and you may enable them via block settings page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out the Views Group By module.

http://drupal.org/node/389230

The tutorial listed above actually describes almost exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are definitely on the right track. But the problem is that digital wants to to show the latest entry under each taxonomy term. I don't know how that possible with group by module you linked too... which also BTW has the additional limitation that you can only use the COUNT() aggregation function in it.