# How can I filter/sort a drupal view in this way?

Tags: drupal, view, filter, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-contextual-filters

I have created a content type called PDF Publication with two fields - a pdf file upload field that allows one file to be uploaded and a term reference field where the user selects an area e.g. area1 area2 or area3

I now need to create a view block that shows just the latest pdf uploaded for each area. so the block will show three pdfs - one for each area

I have followed instruction [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638234/drupal-views-display-newest-content-per-taxonomy-limit-to-one-node) and other forums on the Internet but am struggling to do this.

I would be really greatful for some help, thank you so much for reading.

Comment: The link you included seems to offer good solutions. What is it that you struggle with exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After following the steps in that link I end up with the term name that links to the terms page and when I add the pdf file field I only get the field title and it doesnt display the pdf file field.

heres a screenshot: http://s1287.photobucket.com/user/carlbowles/media/filter_zps452ff086.png.html

Comment: Please don't [cross-post questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102901/how-can-i-filter-sort-a-drupal-view-in-this-way).

Comment: has anyone else got any other solutions I could try?